# Is it possible to have the same source file in two different projects compiled with different options in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a solution with two projects A and B. I have a reference to a source file S in each project, and different compile options for the source. Specifically I am using different preprocessor directives in projects A and B. Schematically I have:

```
Solution
   Project A
      Source S
   Project B
      Source S
```

Is this permitted? Are compile options for S stored at the solution, project or file level?

Comment: Why not put source of S into DLL, rather than including in multiple projects?

Comment: @Ajay so you don't have to modify the file in multiple places. Also, what does putting the source in the DLL mean. If both projects generate dll's, it doesn't matter where the source is, just that it's included in both.

Comment: I am experimenting with subtly different approaches and using ifdefs to modify the code behavior

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, If the source file/code is small, there is no benefit of putting that into separate DLL/Library. But if the the source is big, it is always better to put into some DLL, and let every project (DLL/EXE) use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler options are stored at project level.

**It's perfectly legal to do this**, a file can be part of multiple projects and can be compiled with different options, different paths for headers, different preprocessor directives... you name it.

Comment: Thank you - it was the project level answer I was hoping for